# Is there a general name to refer to a script attached to a particular gameobject in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I am making use of OnTriggerEnter(Collider other), is there a way to get access to the script attached to my other gameobject without explicitly writing the name of the script?
my code is:

```
void OnTriggerEnter()
{
  other.attachedRigidBody.GetComponent<xyz>();
}
```

xyz is the name of the script attached to other, but I don't want to write xyz, but rather want to find a way to make my other gameobject implicitly look for whatever script is attached to it.

Comment: You probably won't be able to do so, because the code needs to know what script to get information from. Though it would be curious to see if anyone knows a way to do this.

Comment: How do you want your code to behave when there is more than one script attached to the object?

Comment: Maybe an interface or abstract class can help you in this case. Then your MonoBehaviours to implement/inherit it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what are you planning to achieve with this, but here you go:

```
other.GetComponent<MonoBehaviour>();
```

Returns you a `MonoBehaviour` attached to the `other`. I am not sure which one, probably the first as seen in the editor. If you want to get all of the components, use `GetComponents<MonoBehaviour>()`.

Comment: and how can I call a specific function  from the script?

Comment: @D.g cast it to `xyz`. Jokes aside, you can use either reflection or `dynamic`, but most importantly: if you have to do this you are doing something wrong, *really* wrong.

Comment: You're correct, it's the first one in the list shown in the inspector. `GetComponent` works this way for any kind of component.